# How to convert Tiff to IMG (ERDAS) format using R programming?

Tags: r, image, tiff, type-conversion

I have hundreds of satellite images in Tiff format in a working directory, that firstly, must be multiplied by 2 , then converted to IMG (ERDAS) format, but **in the same name as input file**.

For example:

input:

```
MOD11A1_2009-04-01.LST_Day_1km.tiff
```

output:

```
MOD11A1_2009-04-01.LST_Day_1km.img
```

So, the first step is to multiply by 2
Then convert from the image from tiff to IMG format.

I wold be very grateful if an R Programming Expert could help me to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And here is dickoa's solution within a loop:

```
library(raster)
input <- list.files(pattern='tif$')
output <- gsub("tif", "img", input)

for (i in seq(along=input)) {
   r <- raster(input[i])
   # using "2 byte unsigned integer" data type
   r <- calc(r, fun = function(x) x * 2, datatype='INT2U', filename = output[i])
}
```

Comment: Thank you dickoa and RobertH. I would appreciate your great help.

Comment: This method, changes the file format from "Unsigned-16 bit" to "Float Double". I did eliminate that in Erdas, but is there any way to say R to protect the file original format?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `raster` package

```
library(raster)
input <- "MOD11A1_2009-04-01.LST_Day_1km.tif"
output <- gsub("tif", "img", input)

r <- raster(input)
r <- r * 2
writeRaster(r, output, format = "HFA")
```

You can also use a loop to process all the hundred files

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @RobertH, we can simplify this code using the `filename` param of the `calc` function.

```
library(raster)
input <- "MOD11A1_2009-04-01.LST_Day_1km.tif"
output <- gsub("tif", "img", input)
r <- raster(input)
r <- calc(r, fun = function(x) x * 2, filename = output)
```

Thanks a lot @RobertH (for the `raster` package too)

Comment: you can combine the last two steps: `r <- calc(r, fun=function(x) x * 2, filename=output)`

Comment: @RobertH Indeed it's more compact like that. Thanks